# Sending to multiple hosts using JavaMail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Can I send mail to multiple hosts like Gmail,Hotmail and so on using JavaMail API

In other words Can I send array of InternetAddress "TOList" or "CcList" where this array contain different hosts ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: Have you tried it?  How about going to the JavaMail docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `addRecipient` multiple times it to add recipients to your email. For example:

```
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("user1@server1.com"));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse("user2@server2.com"));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, InternetAddress.parse("user3@server3.com"));
```

To send an array, you can do the following:

```
Address[] ccRecipients = new Address[] {InternetAddress.parse("user1@server1.com"),
                               InternetAddress.parse("user2@server2.com")};
msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, ccRecipients);
```

Comment: And to be clear, the way email works is you send the message to your mail server and your mail server figures out how to send it to the right servers for Gmail or Hotmail or whatever.